# Optimization of algorithm while

Tags: c, algorithm, optimization

here are 2 codes that give the same result :
Code 1

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int res, nbMax = 0, i;
    unsigned long j;
    for (i = 1; i <= 1000000; i++) {
        j = i;
        int nb = 1;
        while (j != 1) {
            nb++;
            if (j % 2 == 0) {
                j = j / 2;
            } else {
                j = 3 * j + 1;
            }
        }

        if (nb > nbMax) { // <-
            nbMax = nb;
            res = i;
        }
    }
    printf("longest: %d (%d)\n", res, nbMax); 
    return 0;
}
```

Code 2:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int res, nbMax = 0, i;
    unsigned long j;
    for (i = 1; i <= 1000000; i++) {
        j = i;
        int nb = 1;
        while (j != 1) {
            nb++;

            if (nb > nbMax) { // <-
                nbMax = nb;
                res = i;
            }
            if (j % 2 == 0) {
                j = j / 2;
            } else {
                j = 3 * j + 1;
            }
        }

    }
    printf("longest: %d (%d)\n", res, nbMax); 
    return 0;
}
```

the diference is the commented bloc (if). the first time is outside the 2nd while loop, and in the second inside.
the first algorithm should be faster than the second because that scope is executed more times in the 2nd algorithm.
however i get 1second time execution in the first one, and 0.9 in the second...
how can be the 2nd algoirthm faster than the 1st ??

EDIT. I work on MinGW(4.7.1) Windows 8.1 intel i7-4500

Comment: I can't reproduce this. On amd64 gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2 with `-O3`, the first piece of code runs in ~0.30s while the second runs in ~0.33s.

Comment: Same here, can't reproduce it at my end:
`code 1: Compilation time: 0.13 sec, absolute running time: 0.35 sec, cpu time: 0.22 sec, memory peak: 3 Mb, absolute service time: 0.48 sec`
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

`cod2: Compilation time: 0.13 sec, absolute running time: 0.45 sec, cpu time: 0.38 sec, memory peak: 3 Mb, absolute service time: 0.58 sec`


You can also try http://rextester.com/runcode

Comment: What optimization are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce it here, but it depends on the platform and compiler you are working with. Based on the **Optimization Algorithms** used in the compiler, some parts of your code may change.  If something does not affect your code, may be get out of the loop or even be omitted from the code during optimization phase while compiling. You can check the compiler optimization techniques in **Loop Optimization** for some insight.